# Getting error message "Android sdk content loader stuck at 0%"

Tags: android

When I open `Eclipse` it shows the message `Android sdk content loader 0%`. How to solve this? I have turned off project build automaticaly and cleaned all projects in workspace too.

Could someone tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: This is not fun.  Possibly try exiting eclipse and re-starting.  Worst case, deleting the metadata from the workspace and recreating the project(s) does it, perhaps someone knows something more precisely targeted.

Comment: I have found that the solution here worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader/15670474#15670474

Comment: The above link did not solve, So I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23251804/756218 , and trust me , the easiest and a working solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your debug keystore?

`%USERPROFILE%/.android`on **Windows** 
`~/.android/debug.keystore` on **Linux and Mac OS X**

Comment: No i dint do anything !!! but some how its working now..weired!! Thanks for all repliys

Comment: After this, I had to start eclipse twice, create a new project (importing failed), then I can finally see my older projects.

Comment: Really nice. after have tried all solution this only works for me.

Comment: Eclipse is like an old dog from the streets. If you clean (bathe) it, it may die.

Answer (score 23):

Go in the task manager and delete the adb process..then restart you eclipse...

**OR**

Open adb shell with path: sdk/plateform-tools/

Give command: **SDK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb kill-server**

press enter

Again give command: **SDK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb start-server**

press enter

This will restart your adb..Good luck!!

Comment: This corrected this issue for me!  I would select this answer as the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 23):

I too faced similar issue.. I tried many things but none worked.. But then I tried deleting cache folder & ddms.cfg file from %USERPROFILE%/.android folder and from then on it started working properly..

Comment: This should be marked as answer. After so many "eclipse -clean", remove debug.keystore, restarts, adb kills, etc.. only this worked

Comment: Yeah, this is the perfect solution for this issue.

Comment: I did not try other solutions, but this one seemed to be a shorter one, and it worked for me too!

Answer (score 14):

None of the above worked for me - but I found another way to get around this.

1. In eclipse preferences, go to General/Workspace and click the 'Startup and Shutdown' option. In the dialog that opens unselect 'Android Development Toolkit' (and while you're at it maybe uncheck all the other annoying things eclipse does at start up).
2. Restart eclipse and you'll find your Android projects don't work but you don't get the non=progressing content loader initialization.
3. Go back to the General/Workspace/'Startupand shutdown' dialog and enable it again.
4. Restart eclipse once more and after cleaning and rebuilding you may find its all okay for again (was for me).

Comment: Worked for me! in addition to this i close most of the open projects and all opened classes after the first run without the 'android development toolkit'. then i restarted eclipse still without the toolkit to see if my closed projects will be saved. they were saved then i re-enable the 'android development toolkit' and worked just fine again

Answer (score 4):

After trying all options here, I closed all open projects before the progress status could get to "Android sdk content loader 0%" and then opened them one by one.  Fortunately the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Tried all of the suggestions but none seemed to work. This is the workflow that ultimately fixed it for me, not sure why, but it did (finally!). Hope it helps some one!

```
1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Preferences->General->Workspace->Startup and Shutdown->Unselect 'Android Development Kit'
3. Restart Eclipse completely
4. File->Switch Workspace (select a new empty folder as the new workspace)
5. Restart Eclipse completely
6. Go to Preferences->General->Workspace->Startup and Shutdown->Select 'Android Development Kit'
7. Restart Eclipse completely
8. File->Switch Workspace (select your previous workspace).
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem and the solution for me was the same as the answer I posted here:

[Eclipse hangs at the Android SDK Content Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader/19037038#19037038)

which is to delete this file:

```
 /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

Your workbench starts over (return to default layout, settings for AVD's are gone, path to keystores, etc.) but that's not a big deal compared to getting back to work...

Comment: Worked for me on Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 with ADT, no problems with stuck SDK content loader since then.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a frequent, yet inconsistent problem for me lately.  For a while I was turning off the Build Automatically option and closing/re-opening projects.  But I also ran into cases where it would lock up before I could change settings.

Ultimately I discovered that switching workspaces (temporarily) would get it going again.  I now have a dummy workspace with a Hello World project in it.  So now I:

1. Kill Eclipse
2. Open Eclipse to the dummy workspace.
3. Switch workspaces to your desired workspace.

This is the most efficient way I've found to work-around this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be helpful for someone.

If you cannot kill the adb process in Windows Manager, unplug your phone from the usb port.
Then you can stop adb, restart Eclipse and everything works again :) at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I tried to add a project from existing code. I shut the eclipse down and removed the project to another address. I don't know what the problem was but it solved it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I renamed every project folder in the workspace (suffixed folder names with _), then opened workspace and it finished its stupid tasks, then closed eclipse, then renamed the few project folders I really need back to their original folder names, then File > Refresh (keeping the projects that still had renamed folders), then right-click on each project and 'Open Project...'. Saved the day.