# How to Resolving error markers Eclipse Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

After the start of Eclipse i got the message “Android SDK: Resolving error markers’ has encountered a problem.
[image: Resolving error markers]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah , I also faced this problem many times and I got a very good solution , I think It will be helpful to you also ,

**Clean all projects in your workspace and restart Eclipse to solve this problem.**

Enjoy coding :-)

Comment: u are genius ! sir.. save my time  :-)

Comment: ... and when this doesn't work, because Eclipse is "stuck", so it can't execuate any command, including clean, see PeteH's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Cleaning your projects is worth a try but rarely solves the problem. Here's a straightforward solution that you can count on to work.

1. From Windows Start, select "Run..."
2. Type cmd, hit OK (to bring up DOS prompt)
3. Navigate to your eclipse directory

   cd [your eclipse directory location]
4. enter this command into DOS prompt:

   eclipse -clean -refresh
5. The Eclipse splash screen will appear.  Be patient. It looks like nothing is happening but after a few minutes you'll be successfully using Eclipse again.

Comment: What if you are on OS X ?

Comment: @trainoasi - google "osx command line". Look for description of how to open a "terminal" window, which is osx's version of a command line window. Or now that you know what you need is "terminal", google "osx how open terminal window".

Answer (score 6):

I've experienced two flavors of this issue that have different solutions.

1.) Clean all projects in your workspace as the other answers have described.

If it gets stuck on the cleaning the project, because it never gets to that operation in the process queue try these next steps.

2.) Verify that your workspace directory still contains the `.metadata` directory.

3.) Switch workspaces and then try switching back. *You might need to force close Eclipse while switching.*

4.) If all else fails then try manually deleting the `.metadata` directory and then setting the workspace again.

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to me many times as well. Cleaning all projects is the solution. Some times you may end up having to close and re-open your Eclipse.

Comment: I got answer but you are late.

Answer (score 3):

I have also found starting Eclipse with no devices connected gets past the resolving error markers issue. The devices I have been using are 4.4.2 if that helps as well.

Answer (score 3):

all the other solutions did not work for me so I simply deleted all the **.log** files inside the folder **[workspace]/.metadata** and it worked again!

Comment: This worked for me after all other attempts failed. Thx

Answer (score 2):

In my case cleaning all projects was not helpfull.
I deleted .metedata folder and than recreated the workspace.
One of my Android projects contained errors in the build path (previously was not detected by Eclipse) I added it as a general project and fixed errors.

If cleaning does not help recreating the workspace is the fastest way to find the real error.

Answer (score 2):

There are number of solutions to resolve this problem but the Simplest solution is just clean and refresh your eclipse as mentioned below_

`[ECLIPSE_PATH]>eclipse -clean -refresh`

*Example_*

eclipse path on my system.

`C:\Android_new_Setup\Android_setup_10.09.2014\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\eclipse>eclipse -clean -refresh`

If problem is still unresolved [Eclipse hangs at the Android SDK Content Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader/19037038#19037038) will help to resolve the same.

I hope this will help all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your workspace folder and look for any folder that are not listed in your Eclipse IDE. Remove those folders and start your IDE again. That should resolve the issue.