# Eclipse startup hang, "Android SDK: resolving error markers"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am aware that other people have tried to resolve this issue but have thus far found a suitable answer.

The error is, on start up, eclipse gets hung up on "Android SDK: resolving error markers" furthermore, if I try to interact with it, it freezes completely and I am forced to force quit.

This is the progress dialog: [image: Eclipse Progress Dialog]

I find it odd that it needs to resolve the error markers multiple times but I assume this is just for each project in my workspace.

this is my eclipse.ini:

[image: eclipse.ini]

Other things to note being that all that currently exists within my workspace is an Android Application, an App-engine endpoint project for the before application, and 4 needed referenced libraries. All mentioned projects are open. Is this a matter of me overloading the IDE or perhaps there is some loop I threw it into? I find it hard to imagine that this is a unique circumstance.

UPDATE:
When I delete the app engine endpoint project from the workspace and restart eclipse, it loads fine. When I bring it back in, all good. But when I restart from there, it goes into error loop again. I am convinced that I have a circular reference in there somewhere but I cant figure out where. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Restart your computer and see what happens.

Comment: Tried and it didnt work. Please see my update.

Comment: Why did you post the an image of your eclipse.ini here? why not copy and paste the text instead?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. That would just make too much sense

Comment: Yes, easy to fix once, but why does it happen? I have it very often

Comment: I have the same issue quite often, is the project you are loading quite large/ referencing a number of other projects in your workspace? If so, you may consider giving eclipse a bit more startup memory

Comment: Another good option is to close projects before you quit eclipse. Then, on startup, it doesn't try to resolve markers

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This problem made me crazy until I found below, if I didn't post the answer, I am not a man!
Hope this helps if you are also going crazy

I found from [Eclipse Stuck at "Android SDK: Resolving error markers"](http://tekhoow.blogspot.hk/2013/06/eclipse-stuck-at-android-sdk-resolving.html):

```
cd [my workspace folder]

cd .metadata

find . -name .markers -exec rm {} \;

eclipse -clean -refresh
```

if you are in win32

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S .markers') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
```

Comment: This did it! I had temporarily fixed the issue with what I answered with (clearing projects) but this did the trick and did it fast. Great answer

Comment: genius , save my time

Comment: The "find ..." command gives me the error: `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

Comment: Best solution so far!

Comment: Just addition: if you don't know how to launch eclipse (a.e command not found) write: `<path>/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean -refresh`

Comment: @DayDayHappy, you can use more simple way for windows (maybe for unix too): 'del .markers /F /Q /S'

Comment: @YShinkarev, it will leave an empty folder although it will remove all files inside it.

Answer (score 57):

I solved the issue with this (from your eclipse folder):

```
eclipse -clean -refresh
```

I followed this url: http://tekhoow.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/eclipse-stuck-at-android-sdk-resolving.html (but the eclipse command was enough for me)

There is also another stack question with the same topic and say the same:
"**Clean all projects in your workspace and restart Eclipse to solve this problem**."
[How to Resolving error markers Eclipse Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274243/how-to-resolving-error-markers-eclipse-android-sdk)

Comment: i know this is quit old, but thanks bro, you saved the day :)

Answer (score 25):

After trying all suggested ways, the only way solved my problem was deleting this file:

`/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037038/2970351)

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem, and found the solution by going running "eclipse.exe -clean -refresh" from the cmd prompt. The above solution includes other commands done in the .metadata folder which doesn't apply to all versions of Eclipse. I am using Eclipse IDE for Android Developers 23.0.2.1259578.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way of invoking the above answers on Mac OSX:

cd workspace

rm ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/*/.markers

(or)

rm ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/Project-Name/.markers

cd eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS

./eclipse -clean -remove

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before.There are errors in the libraries related to the Google App Engine project, what you need to do is `close Eclipse, go to your workspace and move every other project not related to the Google App Engine project to another location on your computer, then start Eclipse and make sure you resolve all the issues with the backend project ,then copy the other projects back to your workspace.`

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I do not have any other projects that are not related to this in my workspace. I organize by having my reference libraries in one location in my SDK folder, then a new workspace for each 'Project group' (Here being the application and the app-engine projects) then I import as necessary. I switch between workspaces as needed. I am running on a Mac Air which has 4g ram and a 1.8 GHz i5 processor. If I edit the environment to give me half the ram, I think that would be a little absurd but could it potentially be an option. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm.I am not familiar with the Macs but can you try this, import the libraries you need for your project again, this time select the `Copy project to workplace` option.I think for everything to work smoothly, you need to have all the projects + libraries in the same workspace.

Comment: OK I will give this a go.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out a couple days ago and forgot to inform y'all.

all I needed to do was save the projects to some other directory if you have not already. Delete it from your workspace and also delete the app engine endpoints project.

Re-import the android project and copy into workspace. set the java build path and everything else (if it says 'project master' control click -> team -> disable) everything should look fine. Then, delete all references to the app engine project, this means folders called 'endpoint-libs/libcontainers...'

This will break your project everywhere you reference the data model

Now, re-import the app engine project and make any necessary changes so that it doesn't have build errors (warnings may be OK).

Control click -> generate cloud endpoint client library. The libraries in the original project will be replaced.

Not entirely sure what caused this but for the time being it has been working beautifully.

Comment: There are many solutions presented for this problem, but this is the only one that worked for me. Actually, all I had to do was obliterate the workspace, checkout my source from git, and re-import the projects into the workspace. I was not checking generated files into git.

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to do. I think most people's main goal is not to have to recreate their whole workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Great topic!!

After reading all answers. I have found a simple solution and It work fine on windows 7.

I created a file "eclipse_start.bat" with this simple command lines:

```
cd /d C:\eclipse (the directory where is the eclipse.exe file)
eclipse -clean -refresh
cmd
```

Every time i have to launch Eclipse simply I launch this file so the program start without problem.

I tried also another solution. I added this line in the file "eclipse.ini" before all other line

```
-clean
-refresh
```

In this way I can launch directly Eclispe with the same result but in a more cleaned way.

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1):

I have a simply solution without code. Stop the process "resolving error markers" using the red button, then uncheck Build Automatically (Project -> Build Automatically), close Eclipse and open it again. Check again Build Automatically.

Sometimes it happen again, then I do this same process. Boring, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try go to workspace folder, in **\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects**
You will see folders with your projects. Open every folder and remove files ".markers". After restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To me, nothing helped but then I went to .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime and deleted files:

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
```

Eclipse started normally again.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer above - first installing cygwin to get the Unix style "find" installed (note that the  DOSbox "cmd" version of "find" does not work - in the following line at the top of your Eclipse workspace that hangs:

find . -name .markers -print -exec rm -i {}

Note that the "-i" specifies "interactive" remove - and will confirm each ".markers" file that is to be removed.   Then I followed this with a

./eclipse.exe -clean -refresh

in the eclipse folder.   I will check again (after the next hang :-) to see if just the second line is all that is necessary.   Anyway eclipse is happy again and so am I!   Note that installing the full cygwin package takes a while (many hours) - but it is worth it - just start the install at the end of the day and let it run overnight...

Answer (score 0):

go to the eclipse folder with cmd,(Shift+right click on eclipse folder and chose open with command promt)
then type "eclipse -clean -refresh "

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the .marker file from your all project which is exist in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects(your all project).

Answer (score 0):

So on a Mac, with Eclipse ADT, the clean and refresh method did the trick for me. Here are some slight modifications:

Go to ADT Location (if Android) -> Eclipse.app -> MacOS
In this directory you should find eclipse.
Type the following command and you should be good to go:
./eclipse -clean -refresh

Answer (score 0):

Create a text document in the Eclipse installation folder
Paste this command and update with your installation folder name

"C:\Folder where Eclipse is installed\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -clean -refresh

Rename to CleanEclipse.bat and run every time you have this issue
Will save you a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

> I frequently facing this problem. And my final approach was..

1. First open `TaskManager` by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and delete all instance of `adb.exe`. if problem doesn't solve then go to next step without closing `taskManager`.
2. Close Eclipse and also check it shouldn't be running in TaskManager(also finish its process).Then Open %USERPROFILE%/ on Windows or simply ~ on Linux/OS X (You can locate this folder from the Desktop). then open .android folder and delete cache folder and ddms.cfg and start Eclipse. If still your problem doesn't solve follow.
3. If your problem doesn't solve by following above method then go to workspace folder and delete as suggested by this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037038/4260932)

   **/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi**
4. If problem still doesn't solve then Pray to God.