# Android Eclipse ADT build build process enters an unending loop

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt, android-build

I have downloaded latest adt bundle for mac from android developers website. I do create a library project connected to main project and suddenly, Eclipse started to nag! I checked the build progress and I figured out that build process restarts at 40-50%.

I have captured a screenshot:

[image]

Some people suggested to disable `Build Automatically`. After doing this, the project builds and runs OK but I have to build manually after every little change and it's boring.

I am using `Eclipse IDE for android Developers version 23.0.2.1259578`.

Android SDK Manager details:

[image]

What is the cause of this misbehavior? What is a good solution? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution for this issue I have posted a few month ago,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24631434/2970351

Also try other solution in that page if it didn't work for you.