# Updated Adt to r.22 giving errors

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt, android-4.4-kitkat

I have updated to Adt r.22  and now it takes lot of time for the sdk content loader tried solving that referring to

[Eclipse hangs at the Android SDK Content Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader)

now its fine  but every time i open a xml/layout file it shows the 4.4.2 is loading and consumes a lot  of time until the layout shows up.

2nd problem i'm facing is that the Api level rendering to show layouts for Api 19 shows special characters instead of text

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Google fixed these issues in the latest update ADT 22.6.2

ADT 22.6.2 (26 March 2014)  **http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html**

General Notes:

```
    Fixed a problem where Eclipse was non-responsive for a few seconds after opening an XML file. (Issue 67084)
    Fixed a problem where the SDK Manager threw a NullPointerException after removing a virtual device that was created using the Android Wear system image. (Issue 67588)
    Fixed a problem where the layout preview for large screens in Eclipse showed the resources from the drawable-* directories instead of those from the drawable-large-* directories.
    Fixed a problem with Nexus 5 Android virtual devices created from the command line where the SD card file system was read-only.
    Changed the URL for the Android Developer Tools Update Site from HTTP to HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your sdk build tools as well.