# Android sdk content loader at 0%... and nothing works

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Sorry if I'm asking this the wrong way (if I am, let me know what I should be doing instead.) The site warned me not to leave this as an answer and I don't have enough rep to add a comment, so I'm doing a new post.

Basically, I am having the exact same problem as this poster: [Getting error message "Android sdk content loader stuck at 0%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360824/getting-error-message-android-sdk-content-loader-stuck-at-0)

That is, when I open Eclipse it shows the message "Android sdk content loader 0%", and so my projects refuse to build. But I have tried ALL the responses listed there: turning off build automatically, cleaning all projects, deleting my debug keystore, deleting the adb process in the Activity Monitor (I'm on a Mac), switching workspaces, renaming projects, shutting Eclipse down and restarting it. I also made sure to install the latest version of the SDK (4.2, API 17, Jelly Bean). My phone was not plugged into the computer in the first place. I even deleted and reinstalled the ADT. And I STILL get the same problem. Please, somebody, tell me what's going wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Have you tried removing all projects inside your workspace from your filesystem? It could be that a single project is hanging the loader. I also heard that it could be because your internet connection is shaky but that sounds far fetched.

Comment: Take a look at your workspace/.metadata/.log file; there might be some information in there that will help. I'd recommend deleting the .log before you start to make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: ebarrenchea: D'oh! Yes, after doing all of these complicated solutions, I forgot the simple one. I rebooted and everything seems to be fine. Presumably one of the solutions worked but needed a reboot in order to take. I don't know which one it was, but I'm happy to take the working option. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Try this solution, its solve my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15635287/1613433

Comment: This question already has an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader

Comment: Look this link, it may help you :
 [android sdk content loader][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader

Answer (score 92):

Below scenario will work.

Go to your workspace directory `\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\\.projects`

1. Copy `.projects` folder and take backup for temporary.
2. Now Delete `.projects` folder from workspace directory. (**you will not loose your projects**)
3. Start Eclipse and wait for all progress ends at right/bottom corner. Once completed all processes, shutdown Eclipse.
4. Paste `.projects` folder which you have backup earlier to `\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\` directory. Overwrite existing `.projects` folder.
5. Start Eclipse again. And all will work.

In above scenario Eclipse will automatically finds your projects as earlier. You do not have to import manually.

Working for me.

Comment: I tried several solutions for this issue and this is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: this solution worked for me too. i was deleting whole .metadata directory before...

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, too. In my case, I didn't even have to restore the backed-up ".projects" directory. After deleting the one in step 2, after launching Eclipse all projects were still in my workspace, and the ".projects" folder was re-created by Eclipse. Comparing that new folder content with the backed-up folder showed only minor differences in some .index files.

Comment: This worked for me, but afterward implementing this fix I was getting the following error "cannot find the class file for java.lang.object". After I manually readding the android.jar to each project, all of the errors went away... I hope! THANKS!

Comment: Instant solution, but I'm kinda feeling dirty having to do this nasty stuff just to open an IDE...

Answer (score 35):

this worked for me: (the third one always works but its possible the first two work too)

first try this approach:

shut down eclipse then go to `YourWorkSpace\\.metadata\\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench` and remove "workbench.xmi", now restart eclipse.

if the previous approach did not work try this one:

go to `Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\\.android` and then delete "ddms.cfg" and then restart eclipse.

if this one did not work either the final approach will help you which is:

1- before running eclipse go to your workspace and remove one project that is no longer needed (if you face this problem frequently try to import a project before closing the eclipse in order to remove it the next time you want to use eclipse again)

2-go to `Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\\.android` and then delete "ddms.cfg"

3- run eclipse and you are good to go

Comment: It worked..Need some explanation though what was the problem?

Comment: "shut down eclipse then go to YourWorkSpace\\.metadata\\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench and remove "workbench.xmi", now restart eclipse."  
Work for me. Thanks <3

Comment: The second one, "go to Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.android and then delete "ddms.cfg" and then restart eclipse." worked for me. Thank you. 

p.s. I removed the extra "\" before ".android".

Answer (score 12):

I myself ran into this issue, and what have I not tried, all the possible stackoverflow links. None helped.

While eclipse is running and showing me the stupid "Android content (killing me:)".I started the task manager , and I saw adb, cmd.exe is running. Killed it. And voila!.

Comment: This worked for me. Close Eclipse and kill adb. Start Eclipse again and wait until the workspace is loaded againg. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I closed all open projects before the progress status could get to "Android sdk content loader 0%" and then opened them one by one. Fortunately the problem got resolved.

Comment: You were right. I closed just some of the projects and everything looked fine after that! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted there is a couple other answers which may solve your problem.
However they did not work for me but I did manage to find a work around for my particular issue which may help someone.

I believe my issue was with the proxy server at work. While you can configure the proxy in the SDK manager you can't enter the credentials for it to save.

My workaround was to tether my work laptop to my phone WiFi hotspot when I started up Eclipse so it could bypass the work proxy, then use the normal work network after that.

Comment: I've set eclipse to use my Freegate connection, That was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found which works correctly:

Make sure that eclipse is not active. If it is active kill eclipse from the processes tab of the task manager
Open `%USERPROFILE%/` on Windows or simply ~ on Linux/OS X (You can locate this folder from the Desktop)
Go to .android folder (This may be a hidden folder)
Delete the folder cache which is located inside .android folder
Delete the file `ddms.cfg` which is located inside .android folder
Start Eclipse
Hope that this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have many project in you workspace?

if yes, make more workspaces for your project

I have 365 project in my workspace and i often stuck at 0%,then i try to move some project to new workspace. that has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Exit from Eclipse IDE, if it active kill it from Task Manager.
2. Go to `%USERPROFILE%`, then open `.android` folder.
3. Remove `cache` folder and `ddms` config file from `.android` folder.
4. Then start the Eclipse as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The way that works for me *(at least last 2 years)*:

- Go to your workspace in console, enter to metadata: `cd .metadata`
- run: `find . -name .markers -exec rm {} \;`
- Start your Eclipse with `-clean` and `-refresh` keys:

In my case run:

```
/Users/maxim/POC/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean -refresh
```

That's all.

After Eclipse will up, wait for full stuff loading and you can restart it if you don't want to see all log output in console.